# iphone app crashed when tested on iPad simulator

Tags: iphone, nsview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [App crash on iPad simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492647/app-crash-on-ipad-simulator)

`[UIStatusBarWindow convertPoint:fromView:]: unrecognized selector sent to class.`

App crashed with the above message when tried to test iPhone app on iPad simulator.

Testing iphone app on ipad simulator cause was going through apple store review guidelines

iPhone apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]autorelease];
self.containerViewController = [[[ContainerViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
self.window.rootViewController = self.containerViewController;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
 }
```

Do i have to make some changes in settings in info.

Comment: Given that the error mentions `convertPoint:fromView:`, why do you think the code you posted is related to the problem?

Comment: i tested my app again on iPhone simulator and then back on iPad simulator and now it is working. i wonder what was wrong. now it is working fine on iPad simulator